# Alternative definition of joint distribution only referencing induced measures.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

The usual definition of the joint distribution of random variables $X$ and $Y$ requires $X$ and $Y$ to be measurable functions defined on the same probability space $(\Omega,S,\mu)$, so that the function $(X,Y):\Omega\rightarrow R$ defined by $\omega\mapsto (X(\omega),Y(\omega))$ makes sense and a probability measure $\alpha$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ can be defined as 
$$\alpha(A) = \mu((X,Y)^{-1}(A)).\tag{$\star$}$$
This $\alpha$ can then be called the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$.

Notice that it's not enough for $X$ and $Y$ to be defined are defined on the same $set$, as otherwise it isn't clear what to place in place of $\mu$ in $(\star)$ (given that now there's two different ways to measure $(X,Y)^{-1}(A)$).

However, sometimes random variables are defined in such a way that it is not clear what to take as $(\Omega,S,\mu)$. For example, taking $X$ to be uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$ and $Y$ uniformly distributed on $[0,X]$. For this and other similar considerations I've been wondering if the whole reference to $(\Omega,S,\mu)$ can be avoided completely:

**TL;DR:**

Would the following proposed definition for joint distribution be correct:

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be real random variables (defined on possibly different probability spaces) and $\alpha_X$ and $\alpha_Y$ their induced probability measures on $\mathbb{R}$. Then the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ is the (unique?) probability measure $\alpha_{(X,Y)}$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ that satisfies
>   $$\alpha_{(X,Y)}(A\times\mathbb{R})= \alpha_X(A)$$
>   and
>   $$\alpha_{(X,Y)}(\mathbb{R}\times A)= \alpha_Y(A)$$
>   for any measurable $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$.

or is there something wrong with it?

Comment: While that definition would seem to define how the joint distribution would assign probability to some subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$, it is unclear how you would extend it to others! Even if the distribution was to be defined on the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing sets of the form  $A\times \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}\times B$ for borel measurable subsets $A,B$, these limited restrictions don't seem to imply how to measure a lot of subsets, e.g. sets of the form $A\times B$.

Comment: @LostStatistician18, So is it the hopeless? Joint distribution can only be defined when the domain of the ramdom variables is the exact same probability space? I like to think about RVs as distributions on R, and given that different RVs define different (measures) distributions on R, it would be impossible to define joint distribution! :( I have to change my mental concept of RVs then.

Comment: Yes it does seem a little too restrictive to be too useful. I never thought of the fact that the two random variables must live on the same sample space as being too restrictive though! Even if they aren't defined on the same sample space, i.e. $X$ is defined on $\Omega_X$ and $Y$ is defined on $\Omega_Y$, then you could always imagine they are defined on the "enlarged" space $\Omega=\Omega_X \times \Omega_Y$, and $X(\omega_1,\omega_2)=X(\omega_1)$ only depends on the first argument, and similarly $Y$ only depends on the second argument.

Comment: @LostStatistician18 But then how do I define the probability measure on this enlarged space? If I take it to be the product measure, wouldn't that then make X and Y independent?

Comment: For sure. If the way you generate the measure on $\Omega$ is as the product measure based on the "marginal" distributions of $X$ and $Y$, this will lead you to the traditional definition of independent random variables. Generating the measure in a different way would lead you to other joint distributions. This latter step could even by done by starting with marginal distributions and then combining them to produce a joint distribution that is not the product measure, leading to random variables that are dependent. In practice though one normally defines the joint dist. first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition you proposed only captures the cases where $X$ and $Y$ are independent, so it is not sufficient in general. For example, it cannot describe the joint distribution of $X\sim \text{Unif}(0,1)$ and $Y\sim \text{Unif}(0,X)$.

The only case where you can define the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$ when $X,Y$ are defined on the same probability space. Even if it is not immediately clear what the common space $(\Omega,S,\mu)$ should be, it is always possible. Again with your example, $X$ and $Y$ can be viewed as functions on $([0,1]^2, S,\mu)$, where $S$ is the completion of the Borel sets, and $\mu$ is the measure whose density is
$$
f(x,y)=1/x \cdot {\bf 1}(y<x)
$$
Specifically, with this formulation, $X$ is the function taking $(x,y)$ to $x$, and $Y$ is the function taking $(x,y)$ to $Y$.

The way I came up with this was noting that the situation described implied that the conditional density of $Y$ given $X=x$ was uniform on $1/x$, so that $f(x,y)$ was equal to some constant on the segment connecting $(x,0)$ to $(x,x)$ and zero on the segment connecting $(x,x)$ to $(x,1)$. Since the marginal of $X$ had to be uniform, I deduced that constant was $1/x$.

Coming up with the common measure space for two variables described in words takes some practice, but is usually doable using the type of reasoning in my previous paragraph.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm unclear still at two points: I think, even in the dependent case, the marginals of $X$ and $Y$ are given by $P[X\in A] = P[ X \in A, Y\in\mathbb{R}] = \alpha_{X, Y} (A\times \mathbb{R}$. So satisfying that (which was the only condition imposed by my definition) wouldn't imply independence. (I see now that a problem is that two measures on $\mathbb{R} ^2$ may coincide on these types of sets and yet not be equal, so it's not enough to determine a unique joint distribution. And my most pressing concern:

Comment: I would feel like if I have independent $X_1, X_2$, and $X_3$ (which for this to make sense they must have a joint distribution, thus be defined on the same space $\Omega$) I should be able to ask if $X_3$ and $X_1 + X_2$ are independent. But this suddenly doesn't make sense as $X_1+X_2$ is a variable on $\Omega^2\neq\Omega$. The problem is worse even if $X_1$ and $X_2$ aren't independent because then I don't even know where $X_1+X_2$ is defined.

Comment: @JKEG To your first comment, yes, I was mistaken, your definition does not imply independence. The real problem is that it does not _uniquely_ define  a measure on $\mathbb R\times \mathbb R$. This is only possible when $X,Y$ are defined on the same probability space. To your second comment, you are mistaken. $X_1+X_2$ is a variable on $\Omega$, defined by $$(X_1+X_2)(\omega)=X_1(\omega)+X_2(\omega),$$so it makes perfect sense to talk about $X_1+X_2$ being independent from $X_3$.